# How to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH in yocto recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm writing a new recipe for sane-airscan.
I have created a plain recipe without any arguments to make in do_compile.
I'm hitting a error,

ERROR: oe_runmake failed
Package sane-backends was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sane-backends.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sane-backends' found

I can see already PKG_CONFIG_PATH is set in /oe-core/meta/conf/bitbake.conf
What should i still do to fix the issue.

Comment: First, You should include your recipe in questions like this. You don't want to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH: that's already done as you found out. The error is "Package sane-backends was not found": The compilation requires sane backend libraries to be present, which in yocto means you should DEPEND on the recipe that provides them. Unfortunately I don't think that recipe exists: you'd need to create the sane-backends recipe first if you want to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to override the PKG_CONFIG variable with path to your cross-compilation `pkg-config`